# Using Plantuml when publishing on RTD server

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs, plantuml

I just managed to display my documentation on the RTD server.
(https://uracoli-rsensor.readthedocs.io/).

In the Sphinx-RST file I have a ".. uml::" statement, which renders nicely when I build the documentation locally.

In `conf.py` I have the statement:

```
plantuml = 'java -jar plantuml.jar'
```

It references to a local copy of `plantuml.jar` which is not commited to my repo.

How can I write the statement `plantuml = ....` correctly for readthedocs?

Comment: I'd start here: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/specifying-dependencies.html

Comment: Thanks Steve, but the solution was not that easy to pick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial solution was found here:
https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/3885

In `conf.py` add this lines:

```
if os.environ.get("READTHEDOCS") != None:
    plantuml = 'java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/plantuml/plantuml.jar'
else:
    plantuml = 'java -jar plantuml.jar'
```

Also it is documented here:

https://sphinxcontrib-needs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#install-plantuml